# Suspend and then resume a process in python scrip - Linux

Tags: linux, process, python

I am trying to see if there is a way I can suspend and then resume a process in a python script. I get the process pid using os.getpid() and then i suspend the process using suspend(). Is there a way to resume the process without having to manually type "fg" in a shell?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import psutil
import os

sm_pid = os.getpid()
p = psutil.Process(sm_pid)

print "Going to suspend"
p.suspend()

time.sleep(5)
p.resume()

print "process resumed"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a suspension that you can't accomplish with a simple sleep?

Comment: The sleep is just a placeholder here. I'm trying to "pause" a process and then resume it after receiving a user input through a GUI

Comment: Suspend probably isn't the right way (because the process can't wake itself up).  Normally GUIs have a main loop that will accept input signals and execute callbacks, pausing when none are available (often via select()).  I would suspect the specifics of the GUI might matter here.

Comment: My GUI is executing callbacks from a main loop but it is running on a separate thread. I'm trying to pause the process on the main thread from the GUI thread and then resume it by sending a command again from the GUI thread.

Comment: Are these threads separate processes as well?  Suspension is per-process, not per-thread.  You can't suspend only part of a process.  It's possible your question would be better handled by python folks in stackoverflow rather than as a generic unix question.

Answer (score -1):

You could start an asynchronous process
that sleeps for five seconds (or whatever)
and then sends a `SIGCONT` signal to the main process.